# Parser combinator for enumerated values

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

Is there a cleaner way to map a string to an Enumeration value in a parser combinator?

```
object Mode extends Enumeration {
  type Mode = Value
  val View, Add, Modify, Delete  = Value
}

import Mode._

object ModeParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def mode: Parser[Mode] = ("^(" + Mode.values.mkString("|") + ")$").r ^^ { 
    Mode.withName(_) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsers are composable, so as soon as you can build a parser reading one `Mode.Value`, you may compose all such variants with `|` :

```
object ModeParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  val mode: Parser[Mode.Value] = Mode.values.toList map{m =>
    literal(m.toString) ^^^ m
  } reduceLeft {_ | _}
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
scala> ModeParser.parseAll(ModeParser.mode, "Viewx")
```

Comment: A reduceLeft solution is what I was trying to experiment with but couldn't find. Thanks, I'll try that out!

Comment: `literal(m.toString)` allows both "Viewx" and "xView" to parse successfully.  Changing it to use `phrase(m.toString)` instead fixes that.

Comment: I *assumed* you would use it as `ModeParser.parseAll(ModeParser.mode, "Viewx")`, just like the answer from @senia suggests

Comment: I wanted to test it first in isolation and then combine it with other parsers.  I found that when I do `mode ~ anotherParser` then I have to use `literal` instead.  So I've supported both usages by defining a `modeLiteral` parser using your solution and changed mine to call `phrase(modeLiteral)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `^?` method to convert `ident` parser to `mode` parser:

```
object ModeParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  val modes = Mode.values.map{v => v.toString -> v}.toMap
  def mode: Parser[Mode.Value] = ident ^? ( 
    { case s if modes.contains(s) => modes(s) },
    s => s"Mode expected, but '$s' found."
  )
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> ModeParser.parseAll(ModeParser.mode, "Modify")
res0: ModeParser.ParseResult[Mode.Value] = [1.7] parsed: Modify

scala> ModeParser.parseAll(ModeParser.mode, "modify")
res1: ModeParser.ParseResult[Mode.Value] =
[1.7] failure: Mode expected, but 'modify' found.

modify
      ^
```